# Microsoft Dynamics CRM 2011 Column Sorting

Tags: dynamics-crm

I created a list in dashboard. I have 13 columns and 11 of my columns sort perfectly but my other 2 columns cannot be sorted. How can I sort them for example A-Z or Z-A?

Answer (score 1):

If those 2 columns are coming from another related entity or special fields like Partylist, then they cannot be sorted. Unfortunately this is Product limitation.